# How do I send a chart in svg/png to PDFMake

Tags: angular, apexcharts, pdfmake

I am using Apex Charts to show my data from API. I want to generate a PDF report of my chart and include its image. How should I do it?

This is my stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvjrwz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: There are several Javascript libraries that allow you to convert SVG directly to PDF:  https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/, https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert your chart to an image and then you can insert the generated image in to the PDF.

> Since you are using apex chart, which generates an SVG element that
> represents the chart, you can use this element to create an Image out
> of it. Please note that you need to pass correct selector of that
> chart. Here I am passing `.apexcharts-svg` as the selector.

Below is how you can generate an image, this method returns a promise, which resolves to the image data url.

```js
getBase64Image() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const img = new Image();
         const svgElement: SVGGraphicsElement =
         document.querySelector('.apexcharts-svg');
         const imageBlobURL = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' +
            encodeURIComponent(svgElement.outerHTML);
         img.onload = ()=> {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            resolve(dataURL);
         };
         img.onerror = (error) => {
           reject(error);
         };
         img.src = imageBlobURL;
       });
  }
```

next you can call this method to insert the image in PDF:

```js
  async showPdf() {
    const docDefinition = {
      content: [
        {
          text: 'PDF Generated with Image from Chart',
          fontSize: 20,
        },
        {
          image: await this.getBase64Image(),
        },
      ],
    };
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
  }
```

Check this fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuayja?file=src/app/app.component.ts